# RoutedCommand replacement in uwp

Tags: c#, xaml, win-universal-app

I need to create an RoutedCommand in my custome control. I had used RoutedCommands in wpf but in uwp there is no RoutedCommand class. Whats the replacement for this?

[Edit] It seems that the whole CommandBinding which is supported by the RoutedCommand is gone in uwp! Since there also exists no IInputElement which was implemented by the FrameworkElement
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752070(v=vs.100).aspx

Answer (score 0):

The answer might be a RelayCommand, which also implements ICommand

```
public class RelayCommand : ICommand
{
    private Action _handler;

    public RelayCommand(Action handler)
    {
        _handler = handler;
    }

    public RelayCommand(Action handler, Func<bool> p) : this(handler)
    {
        this.p = p;
    }

    private bool _isEnabled;
    private Func<bool> p;

    public bool IsEnabled
    {
        get { return _isEnabled; }
        set
        {
            if (value != _isEnabled)
            {
                _isEnabled = value;
                if (CanExecuteChanged != null)
                {
                    CanExecuteChanged(this, EventArgs.Empty);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        //return IsEnabled;
        return true;
    }

    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;

    public void Execute(object parameter)
    {
        _handler();
    }
}
```

Comment: This is merely a trivial implementation of `ICommand`. The author asks about `RoutedCommand`, which travels across visual tree.